# Is it possible to programmatically resolve producible content-type given a request in spring-webflux?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-webflux

My application uses `spring-webflux`, it still uses classic `@Controller`s with `@RequestMapping`-annotated handler methods.

Some methods produce `application/json`, while others produce `text/event-stream`.

When a request hits a controller, there is no problem: each mapping has `produces` with the corresponding media type defined.

The application also uses `spring-security` (the reactive flavor). If an unauthenticated request arrives, we must build a error response using correct format: JSON for `application/json` endpoints and a Server-Sent-Event for `text/event-stream` endpoints.

The problem is that security checks are made before the request handler is resolved, so Spring has no clue about the correct response media type at this point.

If a client sends `Accept` header, this solves the problem: we just parse it and decide what content type to use, with something like the following:

```
request.getHeaders().getAccept().contains(MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM)
```

(the algorithm is oversimplified, but you get the idea).

But some clients do not send `Accept` header at all. Strictly speaking, we have all the information we need: we have request, and, somewhere in `spring-webflux` beans information about all the mappings is stored.

**So the question is**: how (only having `ServerWebExchange` instance and access to Spring context) do you make use of this mapping information to find out what media types are supported by a handler corresponding to the current request?

P.S. What I tried/thought of so far:

1. Manually maintain list of all streaming endpoints... yuck!
2. Use a bean post-processor to collect information about all mappings and then try to emulate `spring-webflux` behavior... cumbersome and probably fragile.

Comment: Maybe you could create a prefix for all streaming endpoints, e.g. `/stream/**` and for all of the incoming requests for this endpoint you know that the content is `TEXT_EVENT_STREAM`

Comment: @Nico thank you Nico, but unfortunately that's not an option. The API is already defined.